# Portable Settings and App Data Storage, In Python?

Tags: python, settings, persistent-storage

What is a portable way to store settings and generated app data for locally-run (desktop) python programs? Is there some pythonic right-way or a widely used 3rd party module?

Ideally I want some portable way to tie into OS X's defaults system and Windows' System.Configuration system. I'd settle for a way to get the right path to store persistent settings data for the user's OS.

I know about the various relevant technologies like sqlite/pickle/ConfigParser/json/shelve/dbm, but I haven't found a portable way to determine the right *place* for the user's OS and installation circumstances...

For example on Win XP/2000 it would probably be:
`C:\Documents and Settings\<Windows login>\Application Data\<some app identifier>\`

On Windows Vista and Windows 7 it would probably be:
`C:\Users\<Windows login/user name>\AppData\Roaming\<some app identifier>\`

On most Unix-like operating systems it would probably be:
`~/.<some app identifier>/`

On Mac OS X it would probably be:
`~/Library/Application Support/<some app identifier>`

I'm familiar with winpaths (from pypi), but it seems to be windows only. Do you just always use os.path to put a dot file in a users' home directory and hope for the best?

Comment: So after @jannekarila pointed me at appdirs, I used it to make a [usersettings](https://github.com/glvnst/usersettings) module specifically for portable local app settings storage in python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an [appdirs module on PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/appdirs) that should solve this in a portable way.